# TF2 migration for Hydro

Tags: ros, transform, ros-hydro, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Hydro release page indicates that TF has been deprecated, but I still see many ROS packages that still use TF. (robot_state_publisher, navigation, etc)

Is there a plan for migrating these packages? Are patches being accepted for hydro-devel or is the idea to update packages wholesale for Indigo and continue using TF for Hydro?

Looking at the code for TF in Hydro, it appears as if many of the functions are simply wrappers for TF2. So do packages even need to be migrated to use the TF2 package directly? Is there any benefit of doing so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77061/tf2-migration-for-hydro/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#tf2.2BAC8-Migration.General_Backwards_compatability

In short, it should be safe to migrate any package to TF2 at any time, but there's little rush since TF provides TF2 wrappers for existing functions.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-09-11**:
I opened a [pr](https://github.com/ros/geometry/pull/129) to put more stress about this in `tf` doc.